# Extending the Spatie Role Model but use a different database table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

What I need to do is extend all of the functionality of the Spatie permissions package Role model, but use a different table for the derived model.

Right now I have a model SubscriptionPackage that I want to emulate the behavior of a Role such that it can be assigned permissions and in turn this model can be assigned to users. But I wanna keep the Role model intact too.

I have tried extending Yes, but when I create a new SubscriptionPackage, the new record is created in the roles tables instead of subscription_packages table despite specifying the table in my derived Model. As shown below

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Permission; // This extends from Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role as SpatieRole;



class SubscriptionPackage extends SpatieRole
{
    //
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $table = 'subscription_packages';


    /**
     * The permissions that belong to the package.
     */
    public function packagePermissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
    }

}
```

With the code above I expect when I create a new SubscriptionPackage, the record should be inserted into the subscription_packages table but in this case it goes to the roles table.
Any pointers on how to go about this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the [`Role`](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/master/src/Models/Role.php) source code you will this inside the `__construct` method:

```php
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        $attributes['guard_name'] = $attributes['guard_name'] ?? config('auth.defaults.guard');
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->setTable(config('permission.table_names.roles')); // <-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM!
    }
```

So, if you want that your `SubscriptionPackage` to write its records in the right table you have to override this behaviour like this:

```php
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes)

        $this->setTable('your_table_name'); // <-- HERE THE SOLUTION!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Spatie already have 5 tables and fetched data from those only. But still if you want to make the change you have make the changes with table and column name in the model

Answer (score 0):

Publish configuration and change table name in 'config/permission.php'

```
<?php

return [

    'models' => [

        /*
         * When using the "HasPermissions" trait from this package, we need to know which
         * Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your permissions. Of course, it
         * is often just the "Permission" model but you may use whatever you like.
         *
         * The model you want to use as a Permission model needs to implement the
         * `Spatie\Permission\Contracts\Permission` contract.
         */

        'permission' => Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission::class,

        /*
         * When using the "HasRoles" trait from this package, we need to know which
         * Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your roles. Of course, it
         * is often just the "Role" model but you may use whatever you like.
         *
         * The model you want to use as a Role model needs to implement the
         * `Spatie\Permission\Contracts\Role` contract.
         */

        'role' => Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::class,

    ],

    'table_names' => [

        /*
         * When using the "HasRoles" trait from this package, we need to know which
         * table should be used to retrieve your roles. We have chosen a basic
         * default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
         */

        'roles' => 'roles',

        /*
         * When using the "HasPermissions" trait from this package, we need to know which
         * table should be used to retrieve your permissions. We have chosen a basic
         * default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
         */

        'permissions' => 'permissions',

        /*
         * When using the "HasPermissions" trait from this package, we need to know which
         * table should be used to retrieve your models permissions. We have chosen a
         * basic default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
         */

        'model_has_permissions' => 'model_has_permissions',

        /*
         * When using the "HasRoles" trait from this package, we need to know which
         * table should be used to retrieve your models roles. We have chosen a
         * basic default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
         */

        'model_has_roles' => 'model_has_roles',

        /*
         * When using the "HasRoles" trait from this package, we need to know which
         * table should be used to retrieve your roles permissions. We have chosen a
         * basic default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
         */

        'role_has_permissions' => 'role_has_permissions',
    ],

    'column_names' => [
        /*
         * Change this if you want to name the related pivots other than defaults
         */
        'role_pivot_key' => null, //default 'role_id',
        'permission_pivot_key' => null, //default 'permission_id',

        /*
         * Change this if you want to name the related model primary key other than
         * `model_id`.
         *
         * For example, this would be nice if your primary keys are all UUIDs. In
         * that case, name this `model_uuid`.
         */

        'model_morph_key' => 'model_id',

        /*
         * Change this if you want to use the teams feature and your related model's
         * foreign key is other than `team_id`.
         */

        'team_foreign_key' => 'team_id',
    ],

    /*
     * When set to true, the method for checking permissions will be registered on the gate.
     * Set this to false, if you want to implement custom logic for checking permissions.
     */

    'register_permission_check_method' => true,

    /*
     * When set to true the package implements teams using the 'team_foreign_key'. If you want
     * the migrations to register the 'team_foreign_key', you must set this to true
     * before doing the migration. If you already did the migration then you must make a new
     * migration to also add 'team_foreign_key' to 'roles', 'model_has_roles', and
     * 'model_has_permissions'(view the latest version of package's migration file)
     */

    'teams' => false,

    /*
     * When set to true, the required permission names are added to the exception
     * message. This could be considered an information leak in some contexts, so
     * the default setting is false here for optimum safety.
     */

    'display_permission_in_exception' => false,

    /*
     * When set to true, the required role names are added to the exception
     * message. This could be considered an information leak in some contexts, so
     * the default setting is false here for optimum safety.
     */

    'display_role_in_exception' => false,

    /*
     * By default wildcard permission lookups are disabled.
     */

    'enable_wildcard_permission' => false,

    'cache' => [

        /*
         * By default all permissions are cached for 24 hours to speed up performance.
         * When permissions or roles are updated the cache is flushed automatically.
         */

        'expiration_time' => \DateInterval::createFromDateString('24 hours'),

        /*
         * The cache key used to store all permissions.
         */

        'key' => 'spatie.permission.cache',

        /*
         * You may optionally indicate a specific cache driver to use for permission and
         * role caching using any of the `store` drivers listed in the cache.php config
         * file. Using 'default' here means to use the `default` set in cache.php.
         */

        'store' => 'default',
    ],
];
```